# How to call a function which is in another program MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

I write this in my main programm

```
[C,rows,cols,entries] = Matrix('C.txt')
```

Matrix fuction is in another program Matrix.m and I want to call it.

I get this error :

```
Undefined function or variable 'Matrix'.

Error in (line 19)

[C,rows,cols,entries] = Matrix'C.txt')
```

Can you please tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: You probably need to add Matrix.m in you matlab path

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your file and function are not in the same folder.
If you do not want the file and function in the same folder, you can use 
`addpath` to add search path of your function path or folder.

(https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html)